# Facebook Android SDK Login not working with SSO for Second Time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, sha

I am integrating Facebook SDK with my app. First login works fine, but after logging off when I try to login again, Session State comes as **CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED**. And user not able to login. I printed KeyHash and its same as I mentioned in Facebook Console.

If I use following line of code, it works but give user id, password console every time:

```
authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Moreover I do not want to use it like this. Please help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: If you get CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, check the "exception" parameter in your callback. It will contain the reason for why it failed.